# angular compareWith not working in non-material select

Tags: angular, angular-material

I tried to switch from material-based form controls to the 'plain' ones, but I can't seem to get the `compareWith` method to work with this version.

I have looked at many (very simple) examples, and have tried to recreate the most simple scenario possible:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<form>
    <select [formControl]="plainControl" [compareWith]="comp">
      <option *ngFor="let option of options" value="option">{{option}}</option>
    </select>
    <mat-select [formControl]="matControl" [compareWith]="compMat">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" value="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </form>`
})
export class AppComponent {
  options = [1,2,3,4,5];
  plainControl = new FormControl({id: 3, name: 'foo'});
  matControl = new FormControl({id: 3, name: 'bar'});

  comp(o1: any, o2: any): boolean {
    console.log('Comparing Plain');
    return o1 == o2;
  }
  compMat(o1: any, o2: any): boolean {
    console.log('Comparing Material');
    return o1 == o2;
  }
}
```

The `mat-select` correctly triggers the comparing function, whereas the plain `select` does not. Is this a bug in angular or am I missing something?

I am well aware that this particular comparison is useless, I just want to know why the plain version does not trigger.

My Angular version is 7.1.0

Comment: What if you change `value` with `[ngValue]` for normal select? Does that help at all? (so it'll be `[NgValue]="option"`)

Comment: if possible, please create a demo on stackblitz

Comment: @kha Thank you so much, this has been bugging me all day. It worked by switching to [ngValue]. If you write a short solution, i will gladly accept it

Comment: @bmurauer Glad to hear. Added it as a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it from

```
<select [formControl]="plainControl" [compareWith]="comp">
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" value="option">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

To

```
<select [formControl]="plainControl" [compareWith]="comp">
  <option *ngFor="let option of options" [ngValue]="option">{{option}}</option>
</select>
```

Example here: https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor

Comment: For anyone struggling to see the difference: it's `value` to `[ngValue]`